# Communication between android phones

Tags: android, communication, mobile-phones

Is it possible a communication between phones even without internet or Bluetooth in a specific area, lets say 20 meters through a app? Even if both persons dont know each others numbers?

Comment: You mean via wifi? An "app" cannot somehow magically establish a connection if there's no physical way of connecting devices.

Comment: without two hands how can you shake hands. same way it needs some bridge to communicate brother.

Comment: Ok guys i understand that.. sorry if the question is kinda stupid, but i had an idea and i'm just investigating is it's feasible.. imagine, that i have this "app" and other people have the same app and if we are near, like i said 20 meter or something arround that, we can see and talk with eachother, through messages, if all the phones have internet is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If users knows only phone numder - try sms service :) For example. Send sms throught intent and catch sms throught Broadcast

Comment: without internet how can you achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wifi router without internet to do that. Just make one of the devices a server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible for about 10 meters using wifi or direct-wifi. Let one phone function as wifi-hotspot and run your server app on that one. The other phone(s) connect to the wifi hotspot and then your client app can communicate with your server app because it will know the ip of the hotspot.